# Is a React app supposed to do a full refresh on a file refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started messing about with React and on the tutorial it showed one of the benefits: it updates only the necessary DOM elements. However as I started developing an app from scratch I noticed that whenever I save the .js file it does a full page refresh. Is it supposed to do a full refresh if it is a change in the source file or am I doing something wrong that isn't allowing to update only the DOM element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not using Hot Module Replacement in your development environment. So in your case with every change the entire code is getting compiled again and the entire DOM is getting refreshed.
For your reference- https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/